# Deep Learning - classifying whether a given image is an anomaly/novelty/outlier?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, autoencoder, anomaly-detection

I have only "Positive" class image data from an experiment and the task is  to train them using a deep learning network. Anything which is slightly different from the above category should be classified as an anomaly/outlier? [Taking negative class data from the same experiment is quite a difficult task]

P.S : There will be no huge difference between the two classes of data. And the task is to use Deep learning  without having to define or give any features from the images. Also, only a limited number of images (around 300-400) for positive class data are available.

[Positive class Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpkt6.png)

[A simple guess of what an anomalous image would look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oAG8.png)

I believe that this is entirely not an unsupervised learning because I know the labels of one of the classes. I tried using OneClassSVM for this without defining any features (Just tried - not much knowledge about SVM's). 
Also, tried using Convolutional Autoencoders from this "https://github.com/artem-hryb/cnn-anomaly-detection-keras" link and Deep Autoencoders from "https://github.com/otenim/AnomalyDetectionUsingAutoencoder". Some threshold value was set based on training the above models and then it was used to predict if the given image is an anomaly or not. The predictions were not correct.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be of great help.

Comment: Since you know you'r "normal" data, just encode all other data as "anomaly" then you can run a 2 class convolutional neural netowkr

Comment: Hi. If i understand it right, i need "other" class data to encode them as anomaly right!? If i just have "one" class of data, I am not sure how to go about it. Could you elaborate a little bit. (Sorry if this sounds silly )

Comment: For what I understand you have 2 kind of image. "Normal" images, you know in you'r data set what are the normal image, and all "Normal" image belong to the same class. "Anomaly" image, they can belong to different class and you don't know their label.

Comment: Since you' goal is to know if an image belong to "normal" or "anomaly", you can encode assign label "anomaly" to all image which are different from normal class. i'm not sure to understand you'r question (in the main post) very well so I could be wrong

Comment: Oops, sorry for the miscommunication. I absolutely only have one class of data! I don't have any "negative" class data at all to train. The above "negative" image I have put is only a guess of what it might look like.

Comment: If you have no "anomaly" image it's a harder task! I know a lot of people use **variational autoencodeur** which might work better than traditional autoencodeur

Comment: Sure. Will have a look at VAE. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pretrained CNN (on ImageNet for example) to extract a feature vector for your images. Then train an AutoEncoder on that feature representation. This should allow to easier learn higher level differences than directly training an AutoEncoder on pixels.